# How do I see individual field names for a data connetion created from an XML file

Tags: infopath, caml

I have the following CAML template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Batch OnError="Continue">
    <Method ID="1" Cmd="New">
        <Field Name='Title'></Field>
        <Field Name="Monitoring_x002f_Measuring"></Field>
        <Field Name="Legal_x002f_Other_x0020_Complian"></Field>
        <Field Name="Area"></Field>
        <Field Name="Calibration_x002f_Verification_x"></Field>
        <Field Name="Equipment_x0020_to_x0020_Calibra"></Field>
        <Field Name="Compliance_x0020_Monitoring"></Field>
        <Field Name="Community_x0020_Impact"></Field>
        <Field Name="Potential_x0020_for_x0020_Non_x0"></Field>
        <Field Name="Potential_x0020_for_x0020_Non_x00"></Field>
        <Field Name="Significance"></Field>
    </Method>
</Batch>
```

And I create a data connection with it in InfoPath, but when I  add the connection it shows up like this:

[image]

How do I get the field names to show up in that list rather than 'Field' as a repeating item?

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the output, you need to export the form files and hack in some additional information. [This article](http://blog.ianchivers.com/search/label/Sharepoint%20UserGroup%20Webservice) shows how to do it for a different web service but should be helpful.